# Get youtube/vimeo id with pregmatch

Tags: php, html, preg-replace, preg-match

How can I get the video ID for youtube and vimeo videos embed code?  A youtube video embed code looks like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dbPmWbqAJPs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

where the ID in this is dbPmWbqAJPs.

A vimeo embed code looks like this:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/62468031?color=00ff00" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

where the ID in this example is 62468031.

I don't want to replace those exact ids, but rather have a pregmatch/pregreplace that finds the id in any embed of vimeo and of youtube.

Comment: Have you done some research/work? YouTube ids include characters like `-` too, while vimeo ids are numerical.

Comment: I have a couple simple pregmatch snippets but I can't understand how it functions.  Why is this downvoted, is it not a valid question?

Comment: You should include whatever you have tried in the question too. As to the downvote, probably the same reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

vimeo

```
$string='<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/62468031?color=00ff00" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
preg_match_all( '~http://player.vimeo.com/video/(.*?)\?~si',$string,$M);
echo ($M[1][0]);
```

youtube :

```
$string='<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dbPmWbqAJPs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
preg_match_all( '~http://www.youtube.com/embed/(.*?)\"~si',$string,$M);
echo ($M[1][0]);
```

Comment: No need for `\/\/` when your delimiter is `~`.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for php, it works without pregmatch

i.e. :

```
http://vimeo.com/22222222
http://player.vimeo.com/video/22222222
http://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/22222222
http://vimeo.com/groups/groupsname/22222222
```

PHP Code :

```
    $vimeoUrl = 'http://vimeo.com/channels/channelsName/22222222';
    $fetchVimeoIdArr = explode('/', $vimeoUrl);
    $idCounter = count($fetchVimeoIdArr) - 1;
    $vimeoId = $fetchVimeoIdArr[$idCounter];
```